# How to refer to pygame colors with unicode_literals on?

Tags: python, unicode, pygame

What is the correct way to use pygame.Color names when using `unicode_literals`?

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.ver
'1.9.2pre'
>>> pygame.Color('red')
(255, 0, 0, 255)
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> pygame.Color('red')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `unicode_literals` is enabled, Python 2 interprets string literals the same way as Python 3. That is, `'red'` is a Unicode string (called `unicode` in Python 2, `str` in 3), and `b'red'` is a bytestring (called `str` or `bytes` in Python 2, `bytes` in Python 3).

Since `pygame.Color` only accepts a bytestring, pass it `b'red'`:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> pygame.Color('red')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: invalid argument
>>> pygame.Color(b'red')
(255, 0, 0, 255)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> type('red')
str

>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals

>>> type('red')
unicode

>>> type(str('red'))
str

>>> import pygame

>>> pygame.ver
'1.9.1release'

>>> pygame.Color(str('red'))
(255, 0, 0, 255)
```